# Python Array out of bounds error

Tags: python

I am getting an array error out of bounds issue. I am trying loop through a multi-dimensional array and add the value from the formula to each element. How do i fix the loop so i jump out of the array bounds.

```
z=int(4.3/7.9)
V =51
T =51
r = 1
c = 1
a=[[0]*c for i in range(r)]
for r in range(1,51):
    for c in range(1,51):
      a[c][r]=35.74 + 0.6215*T - (35.75*V)**0.16 + (0.4275*T*V)**0.16
      print()
#print to html file down below
outfile=open("c:\\data\\pfile.html","w")

outfile.write("<!DOCTYPE html>")
outfile.write("<html>")
outfile.write("<head>")
outfile.write("<title>Kye Fullwood</title>")
outfile.write("<style> table,td{border:1px solid black;border-collaspse:collapse;background-color:aqua;}</style>\r\n")
outfile.write("</head>")
outfile.write("<body>")

outfile.write("<h1>This is a Windchill table</h1>")

outfile.write("<table>")
for V in range(1,51,1):
  outfile.write("<tr>")
  for TV in range(1,51,1):

    outfile.write("<td>"+str(a[r][c])+"</td>\r\n")

  outfile.write("</tr>")
outfile.write("</table>")
outfile.write("</body>")
outfile.write("</html>")
outfile.close()
print("complete")
```

Comment: your code is dirty remove irrelevant parse and add error stacktrace

Comment: as the previous comment suggests, please remove the code that is irrelevant to the question, and add the exact error you're getting. at this moment, we don't even know which loop you are referring to, there are four in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=[[0]*c for i in range(r)]
```

basically means `a=[[0]]` because your code starts with `c=1` and `r=1`. So when you try to access matrix `a` with indices in `range(1,51)` you got an "out of range" exception, as there is only one element in your matrix.

To create a 50x50 null matrix, the following python idiom could be used:

```
a = [[0 for col in range(50)] for row in range(50)]
```

but I guess from your code that you actually need this one:

```
a = [[35.74 + 0.6215*T - (35.75*V)**0.16 + (0.4275*T*V)**0.16
      for T in range(1,51)] for V in range(1,51)]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're initializing your list the way you do above

```
r = 1
c = 1
a=[[0]*c for i in range(r)]
```

because at that time c and r are both 1, your list looks like this -- [[0]] -- so you're going to get out of range errors when you try to update any indices in the list other than a[0][0]. Because in this code

```
for r in range(1,51):
    for c in range(1,51):
      a[c][r]=35.74 + 0.6215*T - (35.75*V)**0.16 + (0.4275*T*V)**0.16
```

you're going up to a[51][51], when you initialize the list in the first place you would need both r and c set to at least 52.

For that matter, in this code

```
for V in range(1,51,1):
  outfile.write("<tr>")
  for TV in range(1,51,1):

    outfile.write("<td>"+str(a[r][c])+"</td>\r\n")
```

you're just going to be printing the same value 2500 times, because you're never changing r and c in those loops.